# Using AsyncStorage to check Json Web Token in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, es6-promise

So here comes a very common case in my react-native project: check whether the user has JWT(Json Web Token) or not for authentication purpose before the router mounts.

It's easy in React:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem()
if (token !== null) store.dispatch(checkTokenSuccess())
```

But react-native uses `AsyncStorage` instead of `localStorage`, and the asynchronous features have bothered me so much. I can't use async-await inside `App` component because any function with `async` keyword will always return a promise instead of a react component.

Here's my code, apparently, it's broken:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('JWT')
  .then((jwt) => {
    if (jwt !== null) {
      store.dispatch(checkJwtSuccess());
    }
  });

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MainRouter />
  </Provider>
);
```

App always renders before jwt is fetched.

How to let the App Component(root of my entire app) wait until jwt fetch promise has resolved?

**EDIT:**

As @zerkms pointed, JavaScript doesn't block. Then the only solution I can think of is turn the App into a React class and use `componentWillMount()`, but this will make the `App` component unwieldy. Any better solution?

Comment: `await` does not block, so it works exactly as you implemented it.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for the comment! But what's the purpose of await then? And, say I want to block here, what approach should I make?

Comment: You cannot block in javascript.

Comment: "Any better solution?" --- for what? You have not explained your problem.

Comment: @zerkms Have stated the question on the very first line: need to check jwt BEFORE the router mounts.

Comment: Your `checkJWT` doesn't do anything too useful, it's exactly equivalent to `const checkJWT = () => AsyncStorage.getItem('bappoJWT');`.

Comment: @StanleyLuo "need to check jwt BEFORE the router mounts" --- and what to do while it is being checked?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks! I've simplified the checkJWT method, but still the App gets rendered before the JWT is fetched.

Comment: @zerkms Shows "loading...", or the screen gets stuck would both be ok. It's only a very short waiting.

Comment: How do you use `App`?

Comment: @zerkms It's just the starting point of the entire app.

Comment: How do you use the `App` variable?

Comment: Can't your `Provider` do the waiting until the `store` gets filled with the token?

Comment: Yep sounds like a good idea by letting the Provider component do conditional rendering, only renders the router when store gets filled. This would work, thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncStorage expects 2 parameters, `errorCallback` and `value`, you must write your code in this way

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("key",(err,value)) => {
   if(!err){
       console.log(value);
   }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the right syntax. Check the official doc here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html.

Comment: Actually it's still not correct. First argument should be key, then the callback function.

Comment: when i write "value" i'm refering to your string value, i thought it was very clearly...

Comment: That's the argument of callback function; the value should be first argument of `getItem()` function

Comment: @StanleyLuo is right. It should be `AsyncStorage.getItem('key', (err, result) => {});`